# Laggy svg animation

Tags: css, animation, svg

I am currently working on a svg and trying some hover effect... I have a svg map which is divided in 3 parts. On the `<g>` hover, I change the opacity of this group which contains all paths in order to show what area is hovered. It works but I noticed on chrome the animation are not fluids whereas on Firefox they are. 
Here is an example : https://codepen.io/seabon/pen/LOGEoB?editors=0110

Maybe you have an idea why ?

Edit : I noticed I have lags on retina device, on 1k screen it is fluid

Comment: I use Chrome Version 57.0.2987.110 (64-bit) and works fluid without lag.

Comment: I only have lags on retina device

Comment: While I can't see lags on my screen, you should not double the path in two layers, but only transition the color in a single layer. Try if it helps: https://codepen.io/anon/pen/BmjzRm

Comment: Ok it seems to be better ! Didn't know we can use fill on a g tag. Thank you !

Comment: It's inheritable.